# Can I use MySQL functions in the LIMIT offset

Tags: mysql, limit, offset, mariadb

Can I use MySQL functions in the `LIMIT` offset?
Like:

```
SELECT * FROM sites WHERE ... LIMIT FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sites)) , 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that *directly*. `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` values must be constants.

Citation from [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative **integer constants** (except when using prepared statements).

You can use prepared statements and variables, though:

```
SELECT @offset:=FLOOR(1 + RAND() * COUNT(*)) FROM sites;
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM sites WHERE ... LIMIT ?, 1';
EXECUTE STMT USING @offset;
```