# How to use week number to select unique record ID's MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

Not sure if my title accurately explains what I'm trying to do, but here is my use case:

I have a database of Id's `1 = n`, let's call it 500 total records.

I want to first get the week number in PHP `$week = date('W')` so this week is `48`.

Then I want to return 3 unique Id's that would always return the same Id's for that week. So for example.

```
Week 1 = Id's 1,2,3
Week 2 = Id's 4,5,6
Week 3 = Id's 7,8,9
Week 4 = Id's 10,11,12
Week 5 = Id's 13,14,15
Week 6 = Id's 16,17,18
```

And so on.

My approach was to start with week 1, specifying the 3 Id's, then multiply the week by 2 for the 2nd week, then each subsequent week continue to multiply by 2 and add `$i = 1` each week and incrementing `$i++` each week and selecting the next 3 Id's from the starting number. My solution below seems to work, but it feels kinda hokey.

```
$weeks = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$output_arr = array();
$ids_arr = array();
$id1 = 1;
$id2 = $id1 + 1;
$id3 = $id1 + 2;
$i = -1;
foreach ($weeks as $week) {
    if ($week == 1) {
        $ids = array($id1, $id2, $id3);
        $ids = implode(', ', $ids);
    } else {
        $id1 = $week * 2 + $i;
        $id2 = $id1 + 1;
        $id3 = $id1 + 2;
        $ids = array($id1, $id2, $id3);
        $ids = implode(', ', $ids);     
    }
    $output_arr[$week] = $ids;
    $i++;
}
```

So my end result is:

```
$output_arr = Array ( [1] => 1, 2, 3 [2] => 4, 5, 6 [3] => 7, 8, 9 [4] => 10, 11, 12 [5] => 13, 14, 15 [6] => 16, 17, 18 [7] => 19, 20, 21 )
```

Which is what I want, but is there a simpler cleaner way? And, `BONUS HELP NEEDED` it would be a lot better if it could handle a table with non-sequential Id's. In my case, my ID's need to be sequential, if I have a break in Id's EX: `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10` it would mess up the output array.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Then I want to return 3 unique Id's that would always return the same Id's for that week" <- huh... can you elaborate a bit more on this? I (personally) have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @jeto if you look at the desired result you can see what I'm trying to do. I want to get the same 3 Id's whenever I call this function for a particular week. So I would always get Id's `1,2,3` when I pass in week 1, ad I would always get Id's `4,5,6` when I pass in week 2, and so on. I guess I could just hard code all of this since it's just 52 weeks, but it would be nice to have it dynamic and deal with non-sequential Id's in MYSQL so I don't have to worry about it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, if you are not scared off by a bit of SQL magic, you can write a user-defined variable in your query so that all of the info is grouped readily available in your resultset.

SQL ([SQL Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nEfhyfU1sAZUS2UVizH8EC/1))

```
SELECT 
  CEIL(r / 3) AS WeekId, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS Ids
FROM (
  SELECT  
    @rowid := @rowid + 1 AS r, id
  FROM tableA
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @rowid := 0
  ) cjoin
) sub
GROUP BY WeekId
```

Output:

```
| WeekId | Ids   |
| ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 1,2,3 |
| 2      | 4,6,7 |
| 3      | 8,10  |
```

---

**Now, if you don't actually intend to use every row of your database table, then best practice indicates that you should only retrieve the data that you intend to use.**

To access a single set of 3 ids, use php to determine the current week number, divide it by three, round that number up to the next integer, then subtract one so that the LIMIT clause in the query uses `0` (for week `1`) to target ids `1`, `2`, and `3`; and `1` (for week `2`) to target ids `4`, `6`, `7`; etc.

Code: ([SQL Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nEfhyfU1sAZUS2UVizH8EC/2))

```
$limit_offset = ceil(date('W') / 3) - 1;
$query = "SELECT id FROM your_table ORDER BY id LIMIT $limit_offset, 3";
```

p.s. The reason that I am not using pure SQL to perform this task is because: [Can I use MySQL functions in the LIMIT offset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33168004/2943403) .

Comment: I'm not afraid lol, but I've never done anything like that. Very cool; I'll play with it. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose my next question is: How are you next using these comma-separated ids? Not merely printing them to screen are you?  Offering you my best advice depends solely on understanding your start to finish coding requirements.

Comment: @Jeff What is the isolated goal of your code?  Do you only actually need the 3 rows that correspond to the week id? If so, the query can be largely simplified and much code-bloat omitted.  Are you always seeking the current week's id in your query or is this to be determined by a user's selection? Please clarify your question.   I promise it is worth doing.

Comment: thanks for being so inquisitive, it's hard to find help sometime as as a newer coder. The use case is to retrieve 3 pieces of content for a website, but I want that content to stay on the site for a week before the next 3 are selected. So each week a person returns to the site, new content is displayed until all 52 weeks are reached, then theoretically I would revert back to week 1. So to answer your question, yes, I only need 3 Id's back as I"m only showing 3 pieces of content on the site.

Comment: I'm not actually returning only the Id's, I'm getting the full data set (Title, Description, ImageURL, etc.) but for purposes of this question I tried to simplify by asking how to simply choose the Id's, then I can get whatever else I need if I know the Id's.

Comment: After playing with your suggestions, the `LIMIT` `OFFSET` seems to be the simplest and most elegant solution actually.

Comment: It sounds like my `$limit_offset` solution is the best fit for your task.  Otherwise you will be unloading your whole table just to access three rows.

Answer (score 1):

No need to store all weeks in array, a simple function can do the job:

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10);
function weekIds($pWeek){
    $wids = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
        $wids[] = ($pWeek-1)*3+$i;
    return $wids;
}
$seq = weekIds(2);
foreach($seq as $s)
    $nonSeq[] = $ids[$s-1];
echo 'Sequential: ' .print_r($seq,true).PHP_EOL; 
echo 'Non-Sequential: ' .print_r($nonSeq,true);
```

Output:

```
Sequential: Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 6
)

Non-Sequential: Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 6
    [2] => 7
)
```

Comment: ahhhhh @Sal, nice and elegant. Thank you. I tried to write a good question, with my own attempt first as I've been instructed by mods, but still get the `-1`. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pulling all of the data out of your table, ORDER BY id and just call `array_chunk($array, 3)` on your resultset array and access the desired set-of-3 by subtracting 1 from the week number.

---

If you only need to pull the desired three rows from the table, then you can ORDER BY id and set the LIMIT "offset" to (week minus 1) times 3 then the "limit" to 3.