# Floor of decimal as Parameter value in MySQL Prepared Statement throws error

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

**My Goal**:
Select middle row(s) of a table.

**What have I tried**?
I followed the approach mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33168093/282155.
Here's my code:

```
SELECT @a:=FLOOR((COUNT(*)-1)/2) FROM <Table> ORDER BY <Column>;  
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * FROM <Table> LIMIT ?, 1';  
EXECUTE STMT USING @a;
```

But my execute statement throws error:

```
ERROR 1210 (HY000) at line <line no>: Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE
```

**My observations**:

1. Floor of integer works fine when used in the prepared statement. e.g. `FLOOR(COUNT(*)-1)`
2. Execution of floor of decimal also works fine when used in Select statement:
   `SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*)-1)/2) FROM <Table>;`

I am confused why my code is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A table doesn't have a top/middle/bottom unless you define an order and I don't see any ordering criteria being used.

Comment: Correct. Middle is defined only when an ordering criteria is present.   I have updated my code. My **primary concern** is why Floor(<Decimal>) fails in the **prepared statement**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the following equivalent (yet valid) option.

```
SELECT @sql := CONCAT('SELECT * 
                       FROM <Table>
                       ORDER BY <Column>
                       LIMIT ', FLOOR((COUNT(*)-1)/2), ', 1') FROM <Table>;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

And don't forget to deallocate your statement preparation.

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jyuwmCHZrump1d5hQSDMWX/0).